# Why does VS2012 think my command keys are me attempting to edit code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

E.g. when I hit Ctrl-D, I for an immediate window, I have to move my mouse pointer out of the code window, or I get told I'm not allowed to edit code while it is running. I've only recently encountered this.

Comment: Why the downvote here? It's a very real problem; I can't use debugging key chords if my mouse pointer is in a code window.

Comment: When you hit `Ctrl+D` it doesn't tell you it is waiting for the second key?

Comment: Do you have custom settings? With the General settings, VS 2012 uses Ctrl+Alt+I for the immediate window and Ctrl+D is to add a new item to the project.

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing how your Visual Studio is setup, I cannot say.  However, try doing the following:

- Open Visual Studio 2012 then go to Tools > Options...

[image: Tools]

- In the Options menu, go to Environment > Keyboard.

[image]

- From there, click inside the "Press shortcut keys:" input box and, using your keyboard, type `CTRL + D`.  Once you do that, it will show you what command is currently using that shortcut.

[image]

- Finally, type in the command name in the "Show commands containing:" input box.  Click the command name from the list below, then click 'Remove'.

[image]

Hope this is what you are looking for! Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Still didn't wok, bu thanks for the comprehensive answer. I just reset all settings to C# Developer. Those I lost are worth much, much less than the keyboard annoyance.